# Multiple threads updating UI in a surfaceview

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, surfaceview, runnable

I'm developing an android game and I'm just starting, so be kind with your answers

I have a surfaceview which creates several classes which I've implemented Runnable on them, and they receive holder from the surfaceview so they can use the canvas to update the surfaceview.

The problem is, I'm using holder to lock and unlock canvas in each class with runnable and they all update the UI at the same time, thing that I don't want to.

What's happening now:

12:00:00 thread 1 update UI
12:00:00 thread 2 update UI
12:00:01 thread 1 update UI
12:00:01 thread 2 update UI
12:00:02 thread 1 update UI
12:00:02 thread 2 update UI

What I really want:

12:00:00 thread 1 update UI
12:00:02 thread 2 update UI
12:00:03 thread 1 update UI
12:00:07 thread 2 update UI
12:00:10 thread 1 update UI
12:00:15 thread 2 update UI

These times are only examples...

Any idea of how can I use different thread's to update the surfaceview at different times?

Comment: Why do you use different threads, if you need them to be sequential (why not one thread). Also, take a look at volatile variables in Java.

Comment: I need different threads because I'll have different objects on map moving at different speeds. Ok, I'll read about volatile variables ;) Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's calling thread synchronising. If your thread want to update UI , he should wait for another thread, if this another thread is updating. you can search [android thread synchronization](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=android+thread+synchronization&oq=android+thread+sunch&gs_l=hp.3.0.0i13l2j0i13i30j0i8i13i30.557.4813.0.5974.20.19.0.0.0.4.966.6254.0j8j6j5-3j2.19.0.les;eqn,fixedpos=false,boost_normal=40,boost_high=40,cconf=1-2,min_length=2,rate_low=0-035,rate_high=0-035,second_pass=false,ignore_bad_origquery=true,onetoken=false..0.0...1c.1.RMQtfRX5oQA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355272958,d.Yms&fp=c2f54b9677d9ac79&bpcl=39942515&biw=1440&bih=809) , You'll find what you want ;)

Regards Hayk Nahapetyan

Comment: I removed "syncronized" from my code lol I though it would result in my threads updating at the same time but not, they still wait for others to conclude their action... I don't really want that.

Comment: I'm sorry , what you exactly don't want?

Comment: I want two or more threads to update in different times the UI and not at the same time as it is happening now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HandlerThread to get the updates to be done from the Threads.
It would work like this:

```
Private final HandlerThread inboxHandlerThread;
Private final Handler inboxHandler;

public void onCreate(){
    inboxHandlerThread = new HndlerThread("inbox");
    inboxHandlerThread.start();
    inboxHandler = new Handler(inboxHandlerThread.getLooper()){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            UIActivity.this.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}

public final boolean handleMessage(Message msg){
    switch(msg.what){
    case UPDATE_Thread1:
       someObject.setValue(msg.arg1);
       break;
    case UPDATE_Thread2:
       anotherObject.setValue(msg.arg1);
       break;
    }
}
```

and you can simply send a message by `Message.obtain(Handler inboxHandler, int what, int arg1, int agr2).sendToTarget()`

also check http://mindtherobot.com/blog/675/android-architecture-message-based-mvc/ for more info on messages

Comment: Sorry but I did not understood how can this help with my problem... :(